# Unable to link Shared Library with Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, gcc, hyperlink

Disclaimer: I am not a Eclipse coder on Linux and I will refrain calling it names after being unable to create a shell for a simple EXE with linked Shared Library (a DLL in English).

Please be patient - I will describe in detail what I did...

I'd appreciate if anybody can tell me what's going on... I worked with C/C++ Visual Studio for decades but can't figure out what's going on in this medieval tool (Eclipse)...

- I installed Eclipse 2019-x on Ubunty 18.04 and also installed CDT.
- I have created and built a shared library, a C++ Project. The library has a C-style API and a C++ class. It is located at /home/leon/Projects/RLV2
  It builds OK.

RLV2Shared.h

```
#ifndef RLV2SHARED_H_
#define RLV2SHARED_H_

#include "Logger.h"
using namespace CPlusPlusLogging;

#include "shared_EXPORTS.h"  // automatically generated by cmake
                         // by the GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER macro

extern "C" int SHARED_EXPORT ValidateCryptoLicense(const char* token, char* signedMsg, int& signedMsgLen);
//extern "C" int ValidateCryptoLicense(const char* token, char* signedMsg, int& signedMsgLen);

class SHARED_EXPORT RLV
//class RLV
{
public:

    CPlusPlusLogging::Logger* mpLogger = NULL; // Create the object pointer for Logger Class

    RLV();
    void mRLV();
    void InitLogger();
};

#endif /* RLV2SHARED_H_ */
```

RLV2Shared.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "Logger.h"
#include "RLV2Shared.h"

using namespace CPlusPlusLogging;
using namespace std;

int ValidateCryptoLicense(const char* token, char* signedMsg, int& signedMsgLen)
{
    cout << "!!!Hello from ValidateCryptoLicense!!!" << endl;
    LOG_INFO("ValidateCryptoLicense has been called from external module\n");
    return 5;
}

RLV::RLV()
{
    InitLogger();

    LOG_INFO("RLV class constructor has been called\n");
}

void RLV::mRLV()
{
    LOG_INFO("RLV::mRLV function has been called)\n");
}
```

- I also created and built another simple C++ project, "Hello World", a Console application located at /home/leon/Projects/RLVTest2.
  I also created subdir 'lib' under RLVTest2 and in a post-build step of RLV2 I copy the file libRLV2.so to that 'lib'
  It also builds OK.

  ```
  #include "Logger.h"
  #include "RLV2Shared.h"
  ```

  int ValidateCryptoLicense(const char* token, char* signedMsg, int& signedMsgLen)
  {
      cout << "!!!Hello from ValidateCryptoLicense!!!" << endl;
      LOG_INFO("ValidateCryptoLicense has been called from external module\n");
      return 5;
  }

  RLV::RLV()
  {
      InitLogger();

  ```
  LOG_INFO("RLV class constructor has been called\n");
  ```

  }

  void RLV::mRLV()
  {
      LOG_INFO("RLV::mRLV function has been called)\n");
  }

Then I add shared library to exe project:
Project > Properties > C++ Build -> Settings -> GNCC C++ Linker -> Libraries has the absolute path to the library.
-L/home/leon/Projects/RLVTest2/lib
I also added the same path to the library path under C++ General > Path and Symbols > Library Path
I also added the libRLV2.so library to C++ General > Path and Symbols > Libraries of the exe project

Here is the result of the building of exe:

Building target: RLVTest2
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/home/leon/Projects/RLVTest2/lib -pthread -o "RLVTest2"  ./src/RLVTest2.o   -llibRLV2.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibRLV2.so
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:48: recipe for target 'RLVTest2' failed
make: *** [RLVTest2] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

When add library path in the linker as a full path it also complains the same...

Building target: RLVTest2
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/home/leon/Projects/RLVTest2/lib -pthread -o "RLVTest2"  ./src/RLVTest2.o   -l/home/leon/Projects/RLVTest2/lib/libRLV2.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/leon/Projects/RLVTest2/lib/libRLV2.so
makefile:48: recipe for target 'RLVTest2' failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [RLVTest2] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot describe how angry I am at the Eclipse developers (creators)...
I don't care that it is free - if you do something, do it right - without a thought: "I'll do something so smart that they gonna build a monument for me"...

When I changed the content of Project > Properties > C++ Build -> Settings -> GNCC C++ Linker -> Libraries (-l option) to RLV2 linked work just fine...

Comment: ... and now I am getting a message when I try to launch the exe that it cannot load libRLV2.so library